# Supply argument to git command in bash

Tags: bash, git

I do not know bash very well, I currently have this alias:

```
alias pushAndTrackBranch="git push -u origin" #Append branchname
```

Where I type my git branch name manually afterwards .I want to automatically use the current branch so I found:

```
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

And tried to combining them as such:

```
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2 | git push -u origin
git push -u origin | git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2 | pushAndTrackBranch
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2 | echo | pushAndTrackBranch
```

Didn't luck myself into an answer with pipes so I thought as a start in bash_profile I'd assign the branch name to a variable and print it:

```
function pushAndTrack {
  myBranch=$(grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2)
  echo myBranch
}
```

Above is my latest incarnation but it is not correct. How do I fit these two things together? And should I even save the branch name in a variable?

Edit: I see in my function attempt that I forgot part of the command I attempted to save in the variable. It should of course have been:

```
function pushAndTrack {
  myBranch=$(git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2)
  echo $myBranch
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `grep \*` to do? The backslash is consumed by the shell, not passed through to `grep`, so what `grep` gets as an argument is just `*`, which isn't a valid regular expression.

Comment: @BenjaminW., ...how? I see how `grep '[*]'` (my choice) or `grep '\*'` would do that, but not how `grep \*` would unless you have a noncompliant `grep` that silently ignores invalid regex syntax.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yep, realized that and removed comment ;)

Comment: @Adam, ...also, `echo "$myBranch"`, not `echo myBranch`, if you want to emit the variable's value.

Comment: ...that said, it looks like widespread grep implementations *do* behave in exactly that way, treating a leading `*` as a literal character to match, not a modifier to the preceding character (as regex syntax calls for). Nonetheless, I wouldn't recommend trusting that behavior to be portable.

Comment: @Adam you can replace the `git branch ... | grep... | cut ...` stuff with just `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push -u origin $(git branch | grep '\*' | cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

This should do the job. Piping passes the output of previous command to stdin for the next command, rather than as a command line arg.

You may also be able to use `xargs` [(man page)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)